# How to set Label at bottom of the screen in J2ME with LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-container, lwuit-label

I  am displaying the main form in Box Layout.In that box layout,taken Label in another container which has been set as border layout. Now this container is added to main form.

following is my code :-

```
    lblversion=new Label((String)keyvalues.get("lbl_versionnumber"));
            lblversion.setAlignment(lblversion.RIGHT);
            lblversion.setVerticalAlignment(lblversion.BOTTOM);
 Container row0= new Container(new BorderLayout());
row0.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,lblversion);
 this.addComponent(row0);
```

Now my problem is that i want to show label at bottom of the screen,but it shows after all the components have been added in form (not at bottom).

I have also attached image.. you can see it and get idea of it. 
[image]
So is there any option to set label at bottom of the screen in J2ME with LWUIT ?

If any one has idea,please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set Main Form as Border Layout and keep all components in 1 container which should be BoxLayout and then put these container  in main Form with Given Attribute of BorderLayout

And Remove Container from label and insert directly label to main form as such it has been given BorderLayout so add your Label in this Format and all Other components

this.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,lblversion);